# Unable to authenticate to AD using Kinit - cache file not found

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos, pam, winbind

I'm trying to set up Winbind with PAM and Kerberos to authenticate CentOS 7 against active directory.

So far this is what I've done:

```
yum -y install authconfig krb5-workstation pam_krb5 samba-common oddjob-mkhomedir

yum -y install samba-winbind-modules

authconfig --disablecache --enablewinbind --enablewinbindauth --smbsecurity=ads --smbworkgroup={DOMAIN-NETBIOSNAME} --smbrealm={My.DOMAINCOM} --enablewinbindusedefaultdomain --winbindtemplatehomedir=/home/{my.domain.com}/%U --winbindtemplateshell=/bin/bash --enablekrb5 --krb5realm={MY.DOMAIN.COM} --enablekrb5kdcdns --enablekrb5realmdns --enablelocauthorize --enablemkhomedir --enablepamaccess --updateall

kinit -v my.username
```

I receive the below error message when I attempt to get a kerberos ticket:

> kinit: Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found while
>   validating credential

So I tried

```
touch /tmp/krb5cc_0 && chmod 777 /tmp/krb5cc_0 && kinit -v my.username
```

The resulting error is:

> kinit: Bad format in credentials cache while validating credentials

I've also tried creating a local user with the same name as the AD user I'm trying to authenticate as with the same result. Below is the sanitized output of `/etc/krb5.conf`.

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = true
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 default_realm = {MY.DOMAIN.COM}
 default_ccache_name = FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
 dns_lookup_kdc = true

[realms]
 MY.DOMAIN.COM = {
  kdc = mypdc.my.domain.com
  admin_server = mypdc.my.domain.com
 }


[domain_realm]
# .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
# example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 {my.domain.com} = {MY.DOMAIN.COM}
 .{my.domain.com} = {MY.DOMAIN.COM}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the ccache file supposed to be automatically generated per-user? The `[libdefaults]` section of the krb5.conf file was orginally using the kernel keyring with the same initial error, so I tried to use a file path thinking it would be easier.

Comment: Check the permissions on `/tmp` and make sure unprivileged users can write new files to it?

Comment: Try `strace -P /tmp/krb5cc_0 kinit v.user` as root user (for different user `0` should be substituted for coresponding user id) and post output here. It will show what goes wrong when kinit tries to write `/tmp/krb5cc_0`.